# how to do authorization with middleware - gin gonic go

Tags: go, postman, go-gin

i am learning to use middleware with gin framework and i am facing a problem

I want my `Test function` to be displayed in postman only if it has the requirements of my `func TokenAuthMiddleware`

but regardless of whether my body is filled in or not, my test function is being called (with or without authentication) how to resolve this?
i want my Test func to be displayed only after going through the middlewate

I tried something like this:

```html
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

func TokenAuthMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    err := godotenv.Load(".env")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Erro ao ler variaveis de ambiente")
    }
    requiredToken := os.Getenv("API_TOKEN")

    if requiredToken == "" {
        log.Fatal("Por favor, defina a variavel API_TOKEN")
    }

    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        token := c.Request.FormValue("api_token")

        if token == "" {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": "Token deve ser preenchido"})

        } else if token != requiredToken {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": "Token invalido"})

        }
        c.Next()
    }

}

func Teste(c *gin.Context) {
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "sucess": "so beautiful",
    })
}

func main() {

    api := gin.New()

    v1 := api.Group("v1")
    v1.Use(TokenAuthMiddleware())
    v1.GET("/", Teste)

    api.Run()
}
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're *always* calling `c.Next()`, which continues on with the middleware chain or executes the handler. You need avoid calling it when the token is incorrect.

```
func TokenAuthMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    err := godotenv.Load(".env")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Erro ao ler variaveis de ambiente")
    }
    requiredToken := os.Getenv("API_TOKEN")

    if requiredToken == "" {
        log.Fatal("Por favor, defina a variavel API_TOKEN")
    }

    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        token := c.Request.FormValue("api_token")

        if token == "" {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": "Token deve ser preenchido"})
            return
        }
        if token != requiredToken {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": "Token invalido"})
            return
        }

        c.Next()
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use c.AbortWithStatusJSON() instead of c.JSON() and then returning? This function calls c.Abort() internally, which the documentation says: Abort prevents pending handlers from being called. Note that this will not stop the current handler. Let's say you have an authorization middleware that validates that the current request is authorized. If the authorization fails (ex: the password does not match), call Abort to ensure the remaining handlers for this request are not called.

Comment: You could, but you'd still need to return after calling `AbortWithStatusJSON` (or use a big if/else block, which I avoided). ("**this will not stop the current handler**") Edit: I guess the `c.Next()` call would do nothing in that case, so no `return` required, but I'd argue that's much less readable.